# Как узнать позицию курсора мыши относительно экрана?

Tags: c#, wpf, position, cursor

Как узнать позицию курсора по координатам (*X, Y*) относительно экрана, не прибегая к средствам `Windows.Forms`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `WPF` есть класс `Mouse` у которого есть метод [GetPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Чтобы получить позицию курсора относительно экрана можно использовать метод [PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx)

```
private void MainWindow_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var windowPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    var screenPosition = this.PointToScreen(windowPosition);

    this.Title = string.Format("{0} --- {1}", windowPosition, screenPosition);
}
```

Или как еще один вариант - использовать [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorpos).

Comment: @Aplnvent, Я в курсе по поводу `Mouse.GetPosition();`, но как с помощью этого метода получить координаты относительно экрана?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov к результату метода можно применить метод `PointToScreen` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx

Comment: @ApInvent: Вы бы привели фрагмент кода, чтобы не пришлось читать комментарии.

Comment: @VladD Вы правы, добавил пример к ответу.